# Can $L^1$ convergence imply moment bound?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Suppose $M(x)$ is a Gaussian distribution and a series of probability distribution function $\{f_n(x)\}$ convergences to $M(x)$ in $L^1$, i.e.

$$\int |f_n-M|dx \rightarrow 0,$$

In addition we suppose $\int |x|^2 f_ndx$ is uniformly bounded.

Can we prove that $\int |x|^\alpha f_ndx $ is bounded for some $\alpha > 3$ (i.e. $\exists \alpha>3$, s.t. $\int |x|^\alpha f_ndx $ is uniformly bounded in $n$).

Comment: Do you mean for any or some $\alpha$, and do $\alpha$ get to depend on $n$ in that case?

Comment: $\alpha$ is a fixed

Comment: Do you know the difference between "any" and "some"? That is if it's supposed to be true for some carefully selected $\alpha$ or that it is to hold for whatever value of $\alpha$ we chose?

Comment: what I mean is some, can it be proved?

Answer (score 1):

No, you should not expect any such bound.

Define $g(x)=0$ for $x\leq e$ and $g(x)=1/x^3\log(x)^2$ for $x\geq e.$ Let $Z=\int g(x)\simeq 0.0375.$ Take
$$f_n(x)=\left(1-\tfrac 1 n\right)M(x)+\tfrac 1 {nZ} g(x).$$

Since $\int g(x)<\infty$ we have $f_n\to M$ in $L^1.$ And $\int |x|^2 f_n(x)$ is uniformly bounded because $\int |x|^2g(x)<\infty.$ But $\int |x|^{\alpha}g(x)=\infty$ for any $\alpha>2.$